# Sometimes My computer does not know it has a wifi card. What's wrong with it?

Tags: wireless-networking, hardware-failure

Occasionally the computer will behave as if there simply isn't a wifi card inside it.  Not only do the wifi options disappear, the option to turn flight mode on or off also goes.

This is a screen cap of device manager when it is working;

[image]

and this is what it looks like when the wifi cuts out;

[image]

Notice the absent bluetooth and wifi cards.

Is this a hardware problem? Is there any way I can narrow down what is causing the issue?

EDIT; 
The system log in event viewer (problem occured sometime round 6:30pm);
[image: relevent window]

app Log;
[[image: other log4]]

Comment: Have you checked the Event Viewer for any correlated logs?

Comment: @McDonald's no, i will do that next time i see the problem. unfortunately its intermittent and seemingly random. thanks for letting me know it's relevant.

Comment: You can check the event logs now and soon and it may retain the records that are correlated to your problem if it's being captured. The Event Logs will hold data from the past so check the `Windows Logs` --> `System` and `Application` logs and just look around the time you think this happened last by date and time that you can scroll there these with.... check them out and you will see. Type in `Eventvwr.msc` and press enter from Run or even command prompt to open the module.

Comment: If you see errors that may be related, search up on those and [edit] your question and add this detail to help paint the clearest picture you can for people that may be able to help you with it.

Comment: @McDonald's I don't see any errors in the relevent time frame im afraid.

Comment: Is it a laptop? Can you open it? Check that the WiFi card is properly seated and secured. Bluetooth and WiFi are usually on the same card.

Comment: Check when it happens again and post with an [edit] only what you think is relevant to the issue from the event viewer logs

Comment: @DanielB It is a laptop. If it needs opening I will take it to a shop. If I do I will update the thread on what they say the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps might resolve this issue:

- Reset the computer to get the wireless card and Bluetooth working.
- Go to Computer management console:
- Click on device manager
- Go to the properties of the wireless card.
- Go to Power Management Tab.
- Deselect: Allow computer to turn off this device to save power.
- Restart the computer and check if it is still deselected.

[image: Turn off Power management for Wireless network card]

Comment: Please use the formatting guide to understand how to properly format your question before you submit it.